# Ansible: how to compact jinja2 template using conditions

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am using ansible 2.1. Most webserver's has one IP only, but some server's has two IPs. Each webserver has special website for internal usage, i have special variable to define which IP is used for this site: if INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP is null - used main IP, if not - custom IP from host_vars.

content of `roles/web_std/defaults/main.yml`:

```
r_web_std:
  INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP: null
```

content on `inventory/host_vars/100.200.1.2`:

```
r_web_std:
  INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP: "100.200.1.4"
```

(this host has two IP: 100.200.1.2 and 100.200.1.4, and 100.200.1.2 is default IP)

and here is fragment from `server.conf.j2`:

```
DocumentRoot /www/{% if r_web_std.INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP == null %}{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}{% else %}{{ r_web_std.INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP }}{% endif %}/www
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/{% if r_web_std.INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP == null %}{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}{% else %}{{ r_web_std.INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP }}{% endif %}/error.log
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/{% if r_web_std.INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP == null %}{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}{% else %}{{ r_web_std.INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP }}{% endif %}/access.log" combined
```

My eyes!

Is it possible to simplify this?

```
{% if r_web_std.INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP == null %}
{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{% else %}
{{ r_web_std.INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `roles/web_std/defaults/main.yml` to use

`r_web_std:
   INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"`

and just use `INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP` everywhere that needs it?

Answer (score 2):

I like @Kyles approach. But for completeness, you can also use the `default` filter:

```
{{ r_web_std.INTERNALWEBSITE_LISTEN_IP | default(ansible_default_ipv4.address) }}
```